# Android - Is there a way to get properties from ListView?

Tags: android, listview

Just like the title. Is there a way to get components from ListView in other activities/fragments? (i.e. if the ListView shows "apple", "banana", "coconut", is there a way to get Array or something of these words?) Please help me! I'm trying to use the words in ListView in other activities/fragments.
This is my part code.

```
startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            List<String> wordList = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < listView.getCount(); i++) {
                wordList.add((String) listView.getItemAtPosition(i));
            }
            if(listView.getCount() == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "단어가 생성되지 않았습니다.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Intent intent;
                intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Start.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    });
```